# How do I get this floating medallion out of my shower?

Tags: d4-dark-dreams-dont-die

When playing D4 you often come across shield shaped floating medallions you can pick up for credits.

Usually these aren't hard to pick up, and you can select them like any other interaction point.

But I can't figure out how to pick up this one in the shower:

[image: floating medallion in shower]

When I try to select it, I just select the mirror instead.

And when I try to turn around, David's body perfectly covers the medallion:

[image: second pic]

How do I grab this medallion?

Comment: Can you sit on the toilet and grab it